# Xcode 11 iPad storyboard is not full screen. Is it some new behavior or error?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode11

In Xcode 10.3, when I switched from iPhone storyboard into iPad storyboard, everything is working fine, but after upgrading to Xcode 11.1, here is my VC in iPad storyboard:

[image]

but when I switch back to iPhone storyboard, everything is ok:

[image]

In Xcode 10.3 VC is normally over full screen. Is this some error from Xcode 11, or something has significantly changed with new version?

Thanks.

Comment: The default on iPad in iOS 13 is now pageSheet, not fullScreen.

Comment: Attributes inspector > change Presentation to Full Screen. Previously it was a default, now you need to set it

Comment: Is there any way to change the presentation to full screen for all views at once?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the default modal  presentation in now page sheet .  not fullscreen or form sheet . But you can manually switch it